# Multiple $_POST items

Tags: php

I'm trying to post multiple email addresses when a form is submitted but it is only sending one. Here is the code.

```
$email_to = $_POST['emailto'];
$message = stripslashes($message);
$respond = $_REQUEST['first_name'] ;
mail("$email_to,","Website",$message,"From: $respond","Employment Application");
```

Comment: Can you show us the HTML of the form?

Comment: I hope you do understand that without protection this form would be immediately started to be used by spamers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like PHP, do you have multiple "emailto" fields in your form or is the "emailto" expected to have multiple email addresses?

I'd recommend that (depending on your form design) you use a single input field for the "emailto" where emails are separated by a consistent delimiter (coma, semicolon, etc) and then format the list according to the requested format [mail()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) is expecting. A textarea is a common input field for this type of entry.

I also don't understand why you have the coma at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

and make sure your addresses are conform to rfc 2822 (just make a

> var_dump($_POST['emailto']);

) 
and I'm wondering about the additional comma  $email_to--->,<----

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML:
`<input type="text" name="emailto[]" size=20>`

Your PHP code:

`
$array_email_to = $_POST['emailto'];

foreach ($array_email_to as $email_to) {

$message = stripslashes($message);

$respond = $_REQUEST['first_name'] ;

mail($email_to,"Website",$message,"From: $respond","Employment Application");

}`

Comment: Why not just use the BCC field?  It's a boat load more efficient (and faster as well)...